# Which type of character encoding consumes the most memory?

Tags: memory, encoding, unicode, character-encoding

I will store a long (45132 character) string in a Postrgres database whilst preserving every character (including really rare ones).

Postgres can store strings up to 1GB (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29354618/5783745)).

In terms of the maximum size of the 45132 character string, what is the worst case scenario?

By my (possibly clumsy) calculations, Unicode can take up to 4 bytes per character, so a 1GB string would be 250,000,000 characters long (so I would have nothing to worry about), but is my logic/math correct and are there encodings that consume more memory than Unicode that I may need to accommodate?

Note: I assume ASCII is 1 byte per character, and Unicode is up to 4 bytes per character.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the linked article seems incorrect.

According to the Postgres article
[PostgreSQL Character Types: CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-char-varchar-text/):

> The *text* data type can store a string with **unlimited length**.
>
> If you do not specify the n integer for the *varchar* data type, it
>   behaves like the *text* data type. The performance of the *varchar*
>   (without n) and *text* are the same.
>
> The only advantage of specifying the length specifier for the
>   *varchar* data type is that PostgreSQL will check and issue an error if you try to insert a longer string into the *varchar(n)* column.

The size of an encoded character string is dependent upon the default character set
that was selected while initializing your PostgreSQL database cluster using `initdb`.

The only Unicode data type I found in the chapter
[Character Set Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/multibyte.html)
was
[UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8),
specified as containing 1 up to 4 bytes:

[image]

If most of your characters
are Latin1 (8 bits), then an 45132 long character string encoded in UTF8
will take far less than 1 GB or the infinite size mentioned in the article,
much closer to 45132 bytes.